# In Darkness, is Sophia really blind?

Tags: plot-explanation, in-darkness

In the movie [*In Darkness*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5164184/), It appears to me that the blind sibling died and the sibling who wasn't blind pretended to be in order to get the main antagonist (bad guy).

Is my interpretation correct?  Is Sophia really blind?